# Error: Failure reading sector 0x802 from 'hd0' BUT it's a Red Hat 8 VM, now what?

Tags: vmware

I am running a Red Hat 8 Workstation on Windows10 VMware Workstation 16.  I snapped shot the VM and cloned it.  Now I am getting this read error on boot but all the solutions on line for this are are for a "real" computer and not a VM.  (Like how do I use a USB to boot a VM?   Maybe there is a VM USB?)  The snap shot and the clone all have the same read error on boot? The system is just for training so no data loss is possible.  Do I try and fix the Windows 10 VMDK file?

Any help would be appreciated!

...Prof Scott

Comment: I should have said, the VM was running great for the last 45 days until I snapped shot it and cloned it......<whine>

Comment: A snapshot is not a backup. If you cloned the snapshot, you do not have a complete VM.

Comment: Can you start the original vm state without the snapshot.  I will fist bump the "snaphots are not a backup"

Answer (score 0):

> I snapped shot the VM and cloned it. Now I am getting this read error
> on boot

A snapshot is not a backup and so the clone is not a complete VM. That is why it does not start.

Two solutions (only maybe for the first).

(1) You have a copy of the original VM, and then use that.

(2) If you do not have a copy, rebuild the Virtual Machine - that is - start fresh.